# Java getTimeInstance (DateFormat.SHORT) output different format for different locale?

Tags: java, datetime, time, localization, format

**Here is my test to print SHORT format of time for different locales:**

```
 System.out.println(DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()));

 System.out.println(DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.JAPAN).format(new Date()));

 System.out.println(DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("vi", "VN")).format(new Date()));
```

**Outputs:**

- Locale.ENGLISH:       **10:13 AM**
- Locale.JAPAN:         **10:13**              No localized AM ????
- Vietnamese            **10:13**              No localized AM ????

For Vietnamese Locale. I expected result is:  **10:13 SA**  ---  SA equivalent to AM in English

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Most countries use a 24-hour clock, where AM/PM aren't necessary. I don't know what the common usage is in Vietnam or Japan, but in the European countries I know at least, AM/PM are never used. 10:13 means 10:13 AM. For 10:13 PM, we use 22:13. Print  date in the afternoon, and you'll have a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no AM for JAPAN because it is giving you time in 24 hrs format

Comment: So the answer is depending on clock type 12-hour or 24-hour clock that the country use. It is reasonable. Thanks!